# How to make a cite without () with apalike?

Tags: citing, apa-style

For my thesis, I'm trying to make my citations

> author,(year)

but I can only make them like

> (author,year)

I'm using the `\usepackage{apalike}`, but only works with `\cite{blabla}`.

I tried to use `\userpackage{natlib}` for the `\citet` and `\citep`, calling natlib before and after the apalike, but it always gives an error:

```
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined.Or name \end...
> illegal, see p.192 of the manual.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
> Companion for explanation.Type H for immediate help....
> \newlength{\bibhang}
```

I would like to know if apalike has something like `\citet` or if there is a way to use natlib and apalike.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give a small, but complete, example of what you're doing?

Comment: I do somethig like this, i use more packeges, but it will be too long. 
`%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{SCITEPRESS}   
\subfigtopskip=0pt
\subfigcapskip=0pt
\subfigbottomskip=0pt
\allowdisplaybreaks[2]
\begin{document}
blablabla \cite{author1} blabla\bibliographystyle{apalike}
{\small
\bibliography{Bibliografia}}

\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way i could find was:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\let\bibhang\relax
\usepackage{apalike}
```

and now i can use `\citep` and `\citet`, but i didn't find a way to do it without natbib